# Android ExpandableListView

Tags: android

Recently I'm trying to use android's expandable list view, so I googled around and stumbled upon this

http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html

I followed the steps almost exactly, but I created a file just to contain implementation of my own adapter. Basically on my onCreate method of the main activity I call:

```
mEntries = findViewById(R.id.entries);    
ExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this);
mEntries.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here's the code (Taken from above URL and modified):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private String[] groups = {"Vehicle", "Baj"};
    private String[][] children = {
        {"Mol", "Mor"},
        {"In", "Ruh"}
    };

    private Context cxt;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context cxt) {
        this.cxt = cxt;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPos, int childPos) {
        return children[groupPos][childPos];
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPos, int childPos) {
        return childPos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPos, int childPos,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = getGenericView();
        tv.setText(getChild(groupPos, childPos).toString());
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPos) {
        return children[groupPos].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPos) {
        return groups[groupPos];
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPos) {
        return groupPos;
    }

    public TextView getGenericView() {
        // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 64);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this.cxt);
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        // Center the text vertically
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        // Set the text starting position
        tv.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPos, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = getGenericView();
        tv.setText(getGroup(groupPos).toString());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPos, int childPos) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

The logcat spit these:

```
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1276)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:694)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1521)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:900)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-01 22:24:54.883: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14424):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
snip...
```

Anyone care to shed a light on this? =/

EDIT: 
I've already implemented the methods required in the Base class.

EDIT2:
Code added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it... it's at:

```
    @Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPos, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = getGenericView();
    tv.setText(getGroup(groupPos).toString());
    return null;
}
```

It's returning null... I seriously shouldn't code when I'm sleepy =/

Comment: So you should `return tv;` here instead?

Comment: yes, return tv, just like in `getChildView()` Returning null causes nullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

When you extend BaseExpandableListAdapter, you still need to give an implementation on how to show each row. Without it, I think the current impl is to return null which is what you are seeing. So I would also implement:

```
public int getGroupCount()
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

I implemented other functions too but I didn't show them. Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah when I said I followed the steps almost exactly, means I actually have those implemented already. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then you should post your code because without it, we can't see what's wrong.

Comment: It's awfully long, but I'll do it anyway then =/

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your code. I'll have to wait until I have some free time before I can look. Meanwhile, I suggest using a debugger. Or maybe someone else can help

Comment: Logcat is debugger no? Or you're suggesting something better than LogCat?

Comment: No I mean debugger by attaching eclipse or what ever ide you are using to the emulator and seeing where the exception is being thrown